# Asociar un array y tome su posición de cada elemento impreso con un nombre predefinido

Tags: python

> Tengo este arreglo
> ['facebook',
> 'linkedin',
> 'instagram',
> 'twiiter']
> en la pocisión 0 tome el Facebook, en la primera el linkedin  y se deberia imprimir el resultado asi

> Tu nueva contraseña es: [ Facebook: GA&6ggcAF/A6&3d(EGF6B4318#(D&85a, Linkedin :BEceAG94#fdeE(F(8f&Gcc$BG/D!e16f, Instagram : 2G2Be5)eG3f#edCeF$gf4/4(0d5c)18! ]

```
 
   import random

def generar_contrasena():
    mayusculas = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
    minusculas = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
    simbolos = ['!', '#', '$', '&', '/', '(', ')']
    numeros = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']

    caracteres = mayusculas + minusculas + simbolos + numeros

    contrasena = []

    # Añado un bucle más y tu bucle se queda dentro de este
    # Uso _ como nombre de variable para indicar que no se usará el valor
    for _ in range(3):
        # Declaro una variable donde iré almacenando la contraseña que genera el bucle interno
        passwd = ""
        for i in range(32):
            # He simplificado un poco tu lógica en este bucle, ahora passwd es 
            # un string así que no hay necesidad de usar join para unir la lista
            passwd += random.choice(caracteres)
        # Al salir del bucle interno, añado la contraseña generada
        contrasena.append(passwd)
    # Devuelvo el array de contraseñas
    return contrasena
def run():
    contrasena = generar_contrasena()
     # He eliminado el + para evitar la concatenación, cuando se pasan varios
     # parámetros a print, por defecto los imprime separándolos por espacios
    print('Tu nueva contraseña es: ', "\n".join(pwd for pwd in contrasena))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: Hola, @CandidMoe la pregunta es ¿ como asociar el string que imprime a un string de un array predefinido. esto  print('Tu nueva contraseña es: ', "\n".join(pwd for pwd in contrasena))  imprime cualquier cadena de X cantidad y en un rango de X cantidad cuando imprima la cadena esa cadena debe seleccionar el numero de la posición de un string.

Comment: Por que cambias toda tu pregunta?

Comment: Hola @Christian el motivo de la pregunta la cual fue modificada, es que no hay que agregar post innecesariamente y aprovechar los post que no tienen rating, mejorar esa pregunta y mantenerla es la mejor forma de poder tomar cualquier pregunta y que no sea eliminada.

Comment: @KinslertVirguez. quien te dijo eso? los post se puede borrar, y crear uno nuevo donde no se genere confusion con los comentarios ya escritos. Tambien podias responder tu pregunta si encontraste una solucion, para compartirla con el resto. No hay que cambiar radicalmente las preguntas. quien dejo los comentarios se tomo el tiempo con la misma..